# How can I efficiently filter TV series by number of episodes and seasons using the TMDB API in an Angular app?

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, drag-and-drop

How can I implement drag and drop functionality for multiple file upload in an Angular 12 application using RxJS Observables and HTML5 File API?

How can I implement drag and drop functionality for multiple file upload in my Angular 12 application using RxJS Observables and HTML5 File API? I am facing issues implementing this feature and would appreciate any guidance or code examples. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you already tried.